# Java - Grouping unrelated classes under one name

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, attributes

I am new to java and was creating a code where I had a few classes like: `Foo`, `Bar`, `Fiz`, and `Baz`. In my code, all these classes are related, but they don't have any common methods/attributes. I want to be able to access all of their respective attributes and methods while being able to group them together. For example, I want to do something like this:

```java
Grouper abc = new Foo();
Grouper xyz = new Baz();
// Foo has a attribute foosAttr
int i = abc.foosAttr;
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't, and I'm definitely sure that you shouldn't. Without something like downcasting (or type-checking and auto-cast by compiler in kotlin for example) it's not possible - it would break a lot of rules.

In a slightly different way, you could try something with generics like:

```java
class Grouper<T> {
  private T wrapped;
  ...
  public T getWrapped() {
    return wrapped;
  }
}
...
Grouper<Foo> foo = Grouper.of(new Foo());
Grouper<Bar> bar = Grouper.of(new Bar());

int i = foo.getWrapped().foosAttr;
```

Comment: Also, couldn't you do something like this with interfaces? Where you have an interface `Grouper`, which has `getWrapped` which returns `this` when implemented? Would that be good practice and efficient?

Comment: Generics, in and of themselves, are perfectly good practice.  But of course, like any technique they are open to inappropriate use or just plain-old abuse.  Their efficiency is equal to that to ordinary classes.  And yes, you could certainly make `Grouper<T>` an interface instead of a class.

Comment: I profiled this, and startingly, the interface idea ran a bit less than 10 times faster compared to the generics one!

Comment: Well yes, but in my code the Foo and Bar don't know anything about Grouper - and they shouldn't, like you said, they have nothing in common. Grouper is an external entity, a typical util that could be in a library without any knowledge of other classes. Depends what you want really :)